# JSP как обновлять переменные

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, сервлеты

Использую сервлет и к нем привязан jsp-файл. Как обновлять данные jsp-файла из сервлета.  У меня используется 3 кнопки. Пробую так

```
              doGet(request, response);

              if (request.getParameter("button1") != null) // и так далее`
```

JSP-файл.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Game"> 
<h1>Играем в 21(очко).</h1>
У сервера карт: ${serverKart}<br><br><br>
В колоде карт: ${kolodaKart}<br><br><br>

Ваши карты: ${kart}<br>
Очков: ${ozkov} <br>
 ${Ozibka} <br>

<input type="submit" value="Взять карту" name="button1" > <input type="submit" value="Пропустить ход" name="button2"> <input type="submit" value="Рестарт" name="button3">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

И использую к нему сервлет

```
    @WebServlet("/Game")
public class Game extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    CardIgra cardIgra;

    public Game() {
        super();
        cardIgra = new CardIgra();

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);

          if (request.getParameter("button1") != null) {
              String coobzenie = "";
              if(cardIgra.getPlayer().getArrayCard().size() == 5)
                  request.setAttribute("Ozibka", "Пропустите ход, у вас максимум карт");
              else {
              cardIgra.bratKartyPlayer();

                    if(cardIgra.getPlayer().getOzki() == 21)
                        request.setAttribute("Ozibka", "Вы выиграли");
                    else if(cardIgra.getPlayer().getOzki() > 21)
                        request.setAttribute("Ozibka", "Вы проиграли");

              }



            } else if (request.getParameter("button2") != null) {
               // myClass.method2();
            } else if (request.getParameter("button3") != null) {
               cardIgra.startPlayer();

            request.setAttribute("serverKart", cardIgra.getPlayerServer().getArrayCard().size());
            request.setAttribute("kolodaKart", cardIgra.getCardkoloda().size());
            request.setAttribute("kart", cardIgra.getPlayer().getArrayCard().size());
            request.setAttribute("ozkov", cardIgra.getPlayer().getOzki());

            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
            request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

            request.getRequestDispatcher("Game.jsp").forward(request, response); 
    }
    }

}
```